# ShareCompat IntentBuilder crashing every time on Android 4

Tags: android, android-sharing

In one of my activities, I am using the ShareCompat IntentBuilder to allow users to share some text:

```
                ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                    .from(this)
                    .setText("The shared text")
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setChooserTitle("Share to")
                    .startChooser();
```

On Android 5 and above, this works as expected, but on Android 4, I have the following crash every time:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()
at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:4606)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3071)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1180)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Not sure why this is happening, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What device(s) are you testing on? I am fairly confident that `ChooserActivity` works in general.

Comment: I don't have a physical Android 4 device so I was testing in an AVD, AVD's with other Android versions seem to be working fine.

Comment: Well, there are at least six different "Android 4" versions: 4.0, 4.0.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, and 4.4. Which one(s) are you trying with AVDs?

Comment: Sorry about that, so far it seems to be happening only in 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm... I pasted your code into a new application, ran it on a 4.0.3 emulator, and the Messenger app opened. That's the only app on a 4.0.3 emulator that knows how to share text. There's a stack trace in LogCat where `ChooserActivity` leaked an `IntentReceiver`, but I don't get your `onStop()` problem.

There is nothing in your code that is wrong. My guess is that this is some issue with your emulator image setup. You might try creating a fresh image, making sure that you have all the latest updates from the Android SDK Manager (though this image may not have been updated in quite some time).

If you can consistently reproduce the problem with a sample project, since you are getting it on the emulator, [file an issue](http://b.android.com), attaching your project and showing the stack trace.

Beyond that, I really doubt that this is a problem that you will experience on real Android devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: You are right, I tried with a clean emulator, and had no problems.