# File chooser not working in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-intent, filechooser

I am trying to implement a simple Intent.createChooser where the user selects a specific file to load and as a result I will receive the URI if the chosen file.

Now this works fine on Android 5.1.1 and UP. But on Android 4.0.3 (Emulator) I am receiving the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()
  at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:4606)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3071)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1180)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setTitle(R.string.Main_Need_Write_External_Storage_Permission_Title);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.Main_Need_Write_External_Storage_Permission_Message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.General_Notification_Button_Ok, null);

            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, MainActivity.PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            try {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getText(R.string.Main_Select_Recipe_File)), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Main_Install_File_Manager, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getText(R.string.Main_Select_Recipe_File)), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Main_Install_File_Manager, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String filePath = getPath(getActivity(), uri);
                String [] extension = filePath.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");

                if (extension[1].equals("xsud")) {
                    new parseXML().execute(filePath);
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Main_Not_Valid_Extension, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How am I supposed to call onStop() on com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity which is an internal Activity?

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Please post full code `onActivityResult` there is some problem

Comment: Checkout your expection **SuperNotCalledException**

Comment: You appear to be running into a bug in the Android OS or the emulator image. AFAIK, there is nothing that you can do about this bug, though it is possible that the bug only exists on the emulator, not on production hardware. You might try getting rid of the `Intent.createChooser()` calls, and instead just call `startActivityForResult()` with `intent`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ShareCompat IntentBuilder crashing every time on Android 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088261/sharecompat-intentbuilder-crashing-every-time-on-android-4)

Comment: I have edited my post to show the OnActivityResult code. Also, I ditched the createChooser and just used the intent directly, this will open the file manager when I click on it from the list to choose from, but the OS will reboot providing this error: `MainActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8`

Comment: Just tested this again. Everything works fine down to Android 4.1.2. I guess I just have to hope that this does also work on 4.0.3...